# Is there a way to use the markup to put an image into a cell of a table?

Tags: support

LOL - Maybe I should be more specific and ask for an easy way. I've got a feeling that the way that it can be done will be nasty.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; I tested with HTML tables but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I don't think there's a way. Tables are generally not supported. MathJax can be used for simple ones and even then the code can be nasty. ASCII tables are another option. Beyond that, I don't think there is a way. If need be dramatically, make an image.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had tried everything that I could think of, and I made a lot of weird trys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently with the new markup tables you can enter images in a cell. I found out the functionality while writing [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/149952/106377).

And the bonus is that it is quite easy, just make a table as you normally would and insert the image description part in the relevant cell.

For example the code:

```
        | Animal | Image |
        |---|---|
        | Dog | [![Dog][1]][1] |
        | Cat | [![Cat][2]][2] |
        | Harp Seal | [![Harp seal][3]][3]|

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5j8mt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN2hrt.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxGXat.png
```

Renders as:

| Animal | Image |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | [image: Dog] |
| Cat | [image: Cat] |
| Harp Seal | [image: Harp seal] |